# I can't locate the following element in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I couldn't choose (click) the element that in the title and the pic:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7iun.png)

The element is one row in a table.

Here is the element :

```
<span _ngcontent-c37="" class="telno"> +529999111118 </span>
```

I tried that:

```
number_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'+529999111118')]")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", number_element)
```

That is the error I got:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(.,'+549999111112')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-47-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: Can you please share the html of the button, great if you can share the entire row with button.

Answer (score 0):

The tag you have provided is wrong not `button` it is `span`.

```
number_element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'+529999111118')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", number_element)
```

I would suggest use `WebdriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='telno'][contains(.,'+529999111118')]"))).click()
```